# Is histidine drawn wrong in these mechanisms for chymotrypsin?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes

While trying to understand the mechanism of chypotrypsin, I have been looking at a few mechanisms, which are found in my lecture notes, and one found in my textbook. In both cases, it looks like the histidine has the wrong connectivity with the rest of the amino acid chain. Is there a reason for this, or is it an oversight on behalf of the publishers?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under aqueous conditions you can tautomerise the double bond, so it doesn't matter. The two nitrogens are, for all intents and purposes, equivalent.

[image]